# Running issue with meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I just installed meteor following this steps

1. Install [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or any other program that knows how to extract `tar.gz` files.
2. Download the installation archive from
   https://packages.meteor.com/bootstrap-link?arch=os.windows.x86_32.
3. In a command prompt, run `echo %LocalAppData%\.meteor` -- this is the directory in which Meteor should be installed.
4. Extract the installation archive into the directory above.
5. Add this directory to your PATH environment variable.
6. You should now be able to open a new command prompt and run `meteor`. Some versions of Windows may require restarting your machine first.

When I type again into prompt, meteor --version give me this error

```
../node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:51
return function(arg) {
               ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I've already reinstalled Meteor and I get the same error.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the recommended installation method (ie. chocolatey)?

Comment: Just tried with chocolatey method but I get the same error